# How can I display individual feed item images that are defined within an RSS feed (media:content tag) using Aggregator?

Tags: 8, feeds

I'm fairly new to Drupal and as such would appreciate a bit of patience if I get lost in any in-depth explanations. :)

Currently running Drupal 8.9.7. I've been trying to get the Aggregator module to work with `<media:content medium="image" url="https://mywebsite.com/myimage.jpg" width="200" height="300" />` in my RSS coming from another site.

I currently have the Aggregator Feed Item titles displaying along with their posted date in a nice listing view but now I'd like to extend this and add a small image for each feed item which the address for these images is included in the RSS. It's basically a small floating box that shows latest news stories from another site that I manage.

I understand that the Feeds module apparently can do this but since I'm on Drupal 8 it doesn't seem to even let me install Feeds (It just says Feeds is already installed which it isn't. Conflict with Aggregator?).

Is there a way that I can get these `<media:content>` images to display next to these feed items in my view?

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION:**

Thanks so much for the responses. Hopefully this clarifies it a bit further. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish with EACH item (different title,date,description, and image per item) coming from the single RSS feed.

```
WordPress Site RSS Feed:
<item>
<title>News Article 1</title>
<pubDate>Fri, 20 Nov 2020 14:10:58 +0000</pubDate>
<description>A news article.</description>
<media:content medium="image" url="https://www.myfakewordpresssite.com/wp-content/uploads/NewsArticle1Image.jpg" width="200" height="300" />
</item>
```

https://www.myfakedrupal8site.com Aggregator View Block:

[image: Aggregator View Block]

I'd like to load the image from the URL from the remote site rather than having to store it on the Drupal site. I just need to be able to get to that URL so that I can display it in this block view. How can I go about getting to that media:content tag?

Comment: Please describe in detail what you are trying to add: "add a small image for each feed item which the address for these images is included in the RSS. It's basically a small floating box that shows latest news stories from another site that I manage."  Where is this image hosted?  Is it the same image for all items?  "which the address for these images" -- what do you mean by that? Is that the URL of the image file?  A link to a page?  Where does that URL come from?

Comment: I updated the post title how I read it. Please edit it if that doesn't fit.

Comment: Thanks so much for your responses! I've added more information for clarification on this issue. Please let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: @PatrickKenny Do my clarifications make more sense? Trying to make sure everyone is on the same page with what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks so much!

Comment: So the question is, "How can I show images from a Wordpress feed using Views?"

Comment: @PatrickKenny Yes I suppose that is the core issue at hand. I'm not experienced enough to know if Views can be used to solve the issue though or if there are override functions/twig templates, etc that would accomplish this. I've looked into it and the very little information I've found point to template overrides and such like this: [Images in Drupal RSS Feed, without additional modules](https://blog.sam-thompson.info/images-in-drupal-rss-feed-without-additional-modules/). But I'm unsure if this is even relevant or the best method to go about this. Thanks again!